# File Management Section for an Admin Panel

Tags: c#, .net, cloud-service, asp.net, bootstrap

*Initially, I asked this question on StackOverflow.com but I was then recommended to go here and use this site*

I'm developing a CRM Web Application for my client. It includes client management, payments and so on.

The technologies I use:

- ASP.NET MVC 5
- EntityFramework 6
- .NET Framework 4.5.2
- Bootstrap 3

Now my client wants to add a cloud file storage like Dropbox to the Web Application. It should allow uploading / removing files and folders (for admins) and regular users should be allowed to download them.

I think there are some good complete solutions for that so I don't reinvent the wheel. Opensource and Free ones are preferred. I'm looking for a module that I could just set up and add to my existing application.

Comment: Are you OK with running a separate server dedicated to serving the files and allowing admins to manage them? Your app would access the files via the CMIS standard protocol, which has libraries in C#.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Thanks for suggesting, Nicolas! I think that would be overhead for my application. It should be something easy to use and setup, primitive solution. It only requires files upload and removal with basic ACL.